# Using WDS, where are the log files located on the CLIENT trying to capture an image?

Tags: windows-7, logging, windows-server-2012-r2, 64-bit, wds

I'm trying to create a capture boot image for my client machines.  I have the Win7 (x64) capture image loaded in the WDS server and it boots to the WDS Image Capture Wizard with no issues.  I hit Shift+F10 for a command prompt and type "ipconfig" for it to show me NO results.  So my NIC drivers I have used are not the right ones apparently...  My goal for this question is to just locate the log files that are surly generated as the client loads all the drivers and such for me to use the WDS Image Capture Wizard.

So where are those logs located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/936625

It looks like you have to start tracing on on your WDS server first via a registry change (regedit):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Tracing\WDSMMC

Name: EnableFileTracing
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value data: 1
```

Then on the client you're capturing you should be able to see logs here:

```
X:\Windows\Tracing\WDSCapture.log
```